# Did Chaitanya Mahaprabhu indeed say Mahavishnu was an incarnation of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, avatars, bhagavata-purana, identification-request, chaitanya

Any proof in the Chaitanya Charitamrita that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says Mahavishnu is an incarnation of Krishna? Apologies to anyone offended by my question.

Comment: [This site](https://krishna.org/original-sri-caitanya-caritamrta-pdf-books/) has Chaitanya Charitamrita. You can check there.

Comment: What do you mean by `Any proof in the Chaitanya Charitamrita where he recommends the Srimad Bhagavatam?`

Comment: Yes, Sri Caitanya explained that Lord Vishnu is an incarnation of Lord Krishna, as you can see at https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/20 There are many verses in the scriptures that say Vishnu is an incarnation of Krishna. Even in the Bhagavad gita there are verses about that, and in the Puranas also.

Comment: I mean is there any proof in the Charitamrita that Mahaprabhu recommends the Srimad Bhagavatam?

Comment: You mean is there any proof that Sri Caitanya said we should read and learn the Bhagavatam (Bhagavata Purana)?

Comment: Yes I exactly mean that.

Comment: Did you know that the Bhagavatam and the Bhagavad gita are the most read scriptures in the Gaudiya Vaishnava tradition of Sri Caitanya?

Comment: You can see here: https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/9/141/ .  The Lord then continued, “My dear Veṅkaṭa Bhaṭṭa, please do not continue doubting. Lord Kṛṣṇa is the Supreme Personality of Godhead, and this is the conclusion of the Vedic literatures.

Comment: Yes, I have read that story. @RaRe

Comment: I think these are your old questions, most of them you would have got clarity by now.

Comment: @RaRe Yes, in fact, if I'm right, this question was my second question on this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am only answering the following question:

```
Any proof in the Chaitanya Charitamrita that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says Mahavishnu is an 
incarnation of Krishna?
```

Yes, in [Chaitanya Charitamrita, Madhya, Chapter 20](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/20) Chaitanya Mahaprabhu says that Lord Maha Vishnu is an incarnation of Lord Krishna.

CC Madhya 20.250

> prathamei kare kṛṣṇa ‘puruṣāvatāra’
>
> seita puruṣa haya trividha prakāra
>
> “In the beginning, Kṛṣṇa incarnates Himself as the puruṣa-avatāras, or Viṣṇu incarnations. These are of three types.

CC Madhya 20.251

> viṣṇos tu trīṇi rūpāṇi
>
> puruṣākhyāny atho viduḥ
>
> ekaṁ tu mahataḥ sraṣṭṛ
>
> dvitīyaṁ tv aṇḍa-saṁsthitam
>
> tṛtīyaṁ sarva-bhūta-sthaṁ
>
> tāni jñātvā vimucyate
>
> “ ‘Viṣṇu has three forms called puruṣas. The first, Mahā-Viṣṇu, is the creator of the total material energy [mahat], the second is Garbhodaśāyī, who is situated within each universe, and the third is Kṣīrodaśāyī, who lives in the heart of every living being. He who knows these three becomes liberated from the clutches of māyā.’

Answer (score 1):

It is said in the Bhagavatam 12.13.18:
https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/13/18

> Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam is the spotless Purāṇa (***amalam*** — **perfectly
>   pure Purana**). It is **most dear to the Vaiṣṇavas** because it
>   describes **the pure and supreme knowledge of the paramahaṁsas**
>   (**topmost devotees**). This Bhāgavatam reveals the means for becoming
>   free from all material work, together with the processes of
>   transcendental knowledge, renunciation and devotion. Anyone who
>   seriously tries to understand Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, who properly hears
>   and chants it with devotion, becomes completely liberated.

It is said that the Puranas are classified according to the influence of the three qualities of material nature to *sattvic* (pure) Puranas, *rajasic* Puranas (impure with passion), and *tamasic* Puranas (impure with darkness or ignorance). And in the above verse it is said that the Bhagavatam is *amalam* "perfectly pure" Purana, which means that it gives the best and purest Vedic knowledge to learn among all the Puranas. It is even said in some other Puranas that the Bhagavatam is the best of all the Puranas.
That is why Sri Caitanya told to his followers to learn the Bhagavatam.

Here are some quotations from the Caitanya caritamrita (a biography of Sri Caitanya) about the importance of Bhagavatam:

- CC Madhya 25.153, https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/25/153

> Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu advised Prakāśānanda Sarasvatī, “Study
>   Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam very scrutinizingly. Then you will understand the
>   actual meaning of the Brahma-sūtra.”

- CC Antya 13.113, https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/13/113

> Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu said to Raghunātha Bhaṭṭa, “When you return
>   home, serve your aged father and mother, who are devotees, and try to
>   study Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam from a pure Vaiṣṇava who has realized God.”

- CC Madhya 19.115, https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/19/115

> Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu taught Śrīla Rūpa Gosvāmī the ultimate limit
>   of the truth about Lord Kṛṣṇa, the truth about devotional service and
>   the truth about transcendental mellows, culminating in conjugal love
>   between Rādhā and Kṛṣṇa. Finally He told Rūpa Gosvāmī about the
>   ultimate conclusions of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam.

The followers of Sri Caitanya also used to study or recite the Bhagavatam together with the learned men of the society:

- CC Madhya 19.17, https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/19/17

> Śrī Sanātana Gosvāmī used to discuss Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam in an assembly
>   of twenty or thirty learned brāhmaṇa scholars.

- CC Ādi 10.158, https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/10/158

> While he (Raghunātha Bhaṭṭa Gosvāmī) stayed with Śrīla Rūpa Gosvāmī, his engagement was to recite
>   Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam for him to hear. As a result of this Bhāgavatam
>   recitation, he attained perfectional love of Kṛṣṇa, by which he
>   remained always maddened.

I suggest you read the purports to those verses at the above links.

Comment: Now OP edited his question. This answer no longer answers the question. Can you edit it accordingly?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think that people shouldn't do that thing on this website. Once they post their Q they shouldn't change it so that the answer becomes obsolete!  I think that thing should be forbidden.